# Form builder angular Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

hi can someone explain me why i get error like my title ,
i use form builder and also i import reactive form module and forms module in my own module and my app module but still get errorl like this Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'

[my Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mNwi.png)

[my Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOIEl.png)

[my own module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBmz0.png)

[app module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEbFO.png)

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to register AddQuotesComponent in Module. Look at the declaration array you will not find the AddQuotesComponent.

Comment: damnn :D , ohh i see , thankyou i really confiused , yes im forgot to regiter my component to my own module ,basically angular register automatically in my module after generate component